# Python Tkinter Scrollbar within a Class

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

My goal is to create a GUI TKinter class with vertical and horizontal scrolls.

I have a chart whose dimension is bigger than the window dimension of the GUI. I put the chart within a canvas to enable the scrollbar function that allows vertical and horizontal scroll.

However when I run my code, the graph size fits automatically to the size of the GUI window thus distorting the graph ratio and the scrollbar function is not working.

Does anyone know the solution to this? Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import * 

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Frame_parent = Frame(self, bg = 'white', borderwidth = 0, relief = FLAT)
        Frame_parent.pack(side = TOP, padx = 1, pady = 1)

        Canvas_parent = Canvas(Frame_parent, scrollregion = (0, 0, 2000, 2000))
        vbar=Scrollbar(Frame_parent, orient = VERTICAL)
        vbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        vbar.config(command = Canvas_parent.yview)
        hbar=Scrollbar(Frame_parent, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        hbar.config(command=Canvas_parent.xview)

        Canvas_parent.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand = vbar.set)
        Canvas_parent.pack(side = LEFT, expand = True, fill = BOTH)

        Frame_child = Frame(Canvas_parent, bg = 'white', borderwidth = 2, relief = FLAT)
        Frame_child.pack(side = TOP, padx = 10, pady = 1)


        f = Figure(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        a.plot(t, s)


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, Frame_child)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = BOTTOM,  fill = BOTH,  expand = False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry("400x400+51+51")
    app.title("Test")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note I would like to point to is that you have many useless container widgets. So in my solution below, I will remove away all that useless code; I mean all what is related to `Frame_parent`,  `Frame_child` and `Canvas_parent`. Note that in my solution below, I can let those widget in place, but by principle, I do not code something I do not use.

Second important note is that you want to scroll the chart of `canvas` but your code is trying to scroll `Canvas_parent` widget. And that is the core of your problem. So you will need to use [`FigureCanvasTkAgg.get_tk_widget()`](http://matplotlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.99.3-1ubuntu4/classmatplotlib_1_1backends_1_1backend__tkagg_1_1FigureCanvasTkAgg_a391d2a61345f459def359cd2388cd487.html) and apply `config()` method on the  object it returns.

This means you will need to change:

```
Canvas_parent.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand = vbar.set)
```

To:

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
```

Here is the solution:

```
from tkinter import * 

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.configure(width=400, height=400)


        f = Figure(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        a.plot(t, s)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        vbar=Scrollbar(self, orient = VERTICAL)
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1)       
        hbar=Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.grid(row=1, column=0)


        canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand = vbar.set)

        hbar.config(command=canvas.get_tk_widget().xview)
        vbar.config(command=canvas.get_tk_widget().yview)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry("400x400+51+51")
    app.title("Test")
    app.mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot of the running above program:

[image]

Note that if you want to stretch the scrollbars to look longer as in your code, you can add the option `vbar.grid(..., sticky=N+S, ...)` for `hbar` and `hbar.grid(..., sticky=W+E, ...)` for `hbar`.

Comment: It works. Thank you very for the feedback and the code explanation. I have more understanding of how the scrollbar works at tkinter.